# How to add r.vieshed.cva to QGIS 2.18.3 processing toolbox?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, viewshed, grass-7.2

I want to add r.vieshed.cva on my grass 7.2.0 from QGIS 2.18.3.
I need to access to r.vieshed.cva from processing and conect it with processing.runalg().
I saved the alg on C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\grass7 as python file but it doesn't appear on processing tools on QGIS or GRASS.

I want to add the result os a first processing in r.viewshed.cva vector file.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try saving the algorithm as a **.txt** file in the `C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description/` directory.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't appear.I saved the *.py as a .txt in this path

Comment: Hi,Do you know another way to access to algoritm from processing? I need to join a export shp from a preview comand as r.vieshed.cva vector file.